# PHP Convert date Timezone to Epoch

Tags: php

Any help with PHP to convert the below, taking into consideration the time zone at the end, to UNIX epoch for MYSQL insert.

29/05/2022 22:23:04 +00:00

No examples of attempts :-/ Tried basic `strtotime` on it's own.

Comment: Have you simply looked at [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)?

Comment: Something like `DateTime($your_date, new DateTimeZone($time_zone));`  -- But you will need to know the time zone IE `GMT` or `PST` which you could easily write (or find) an array for. -- Something like [THIS](https://gist.github.com/pavellauko/3082580) -- Not exactly what you need .. But the gist is there ..

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat

Comment: Being easy to find in the manual does not preclude a question on StackOverflow. If the question were a duplicate StackOverflow question, then it might not belong here. StackOverflow is a good place to find answers as a go-to option even before looking in the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just [parse the date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and call [getTimestamp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php).

```php
$unixtime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s P', '29/05/2022 22:23:04 +00:00')->getTimestamp();

echo $unixtime;
```

Output:

```
1653862984
```

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of helping someone out in a pinch .. You need to do something like this.  I don't know your exact timezones, if they are `+0:00` or `+00:00` .. But this will get you started as a stand-alone app that you can form into your own script...

```
<?php
$zones =array(
'-10:00' => 'America/Atka',
'-09:00' => 'America/Yakutat',
'-08:00' => 'Mexico/BajaNorte',
'-07:00' => 'Mexico/BajaSur',
'-06:00' => 'Mexico/General',
'-05:00' => 'Canada/Eastern',
'-04:-30' => 'America/Caracas',
'-04:00' => 'Chile/Continental',
'-03:-30' => 'Canada/Newfoundland',
'-03:00' => 'Brazil/East',
'-02:00' => 'Brazil/DeNoronha',
'-01:00' => 'Atlantic/Cape_Verde',
'+00:00' => 'Europe/London',
'+01:00' => 'Europe/Zurich',
'+02:00' => 'Europe/Zaporozhye',
'+03:00' => 'Indian/Mayotte',
'+03:30' => 'Asia/Tehran',
'+04:00' => 'Indian/Reunion',
'+04:30' => 'Asia/Kabul',
'+05:00' => 'Indian/Maldives',
'+05:30' => 'Asia/Kolkata',
'+05:45' => 'Asia/Katmandu',
'+06:00' => 'Indian/Chagos',
'+06:30' => 'Indian/Cocos',
'+07:00' => 'Indian/Christmas',
'+08:00' => 'Australia/West',
'+08:45' => 'Australia/Eucla',
'+09:00' => 'Asia/Yakutsk',
'+09:30' => 'Australia/Yancowinna',
'+10:00' => 'Australia/Victoria',
'+10:30' => 'Australia/Lord_Howe',
'+11:00' => 'Asia/Magadan',
'+12:00' => 'Asia/Kamchatka'
);



$my_time = '29/05/2022 22:23:04 +00:00';

$time_split = explode(' ', $my_time);
$my_date = $time_split[0];
$my_time = $time_split[1];
$my_zone = $time_split[2];


$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y G:H:s', "$my_date $my_time");
$timezone = new DateTimeZone($zones[$my_zone]);
$datetime->setTimezone($timezone);
echo "Your Date:Time: " . $datetime->format('F d, Y H:i') . "\n";
echo "Your EPOCH: " . strtotime($datetime->format('F d, Y H:i')) . "\n";
```

Comment: There is a format specifier for timezone.